# Can I use "the ahead vehicle"?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

If there are two vehicles on a road, and I want to differentiate them, can I say "the ahead vehicle", using ahead as an adjective?

Comment: Putting it that way isn't idiomatic: we would more normally say "the vehicle (which is) ahead".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - "ahead" is an adverb and is always relative to something:

- One car is ahead of the other (compares the two positions)
- On the road ahead (compares to your relative position)

In your context, referring to a vehicle that is ahead of another, you could say:

- The car *in front*.

or, if the cars were competing in a race, you might say:

- The car *in the lead*.

Comment: OK, except that in modern grammar, "ahead" is a preposition, not an adverb.

Comment: I don't see how this "explains" anything. Saying that "ahead" is always relative to something doesn't mean much when in your second example (and OP's context), it's just an implied *relative to **your** position*, or *relative to the **other** car*. And if the relevant "grammatical label" can vary between "adverb" and "preposition" (neither of which are usually clear-cut elements for a learner), I don't see the point of the labels either. The point is that *idiomatically*, "ahead" (unlike, say, "leading" or "next") always appears ***after*** the noun it modifies, never before.

Comment: (Whereas certain similar words, such as ***above***, can come before *or* after the noun they modify. And I don't think it matters whether you call ***above*** a preposition, an adverb, or an adjective - that won't explain why not *all* such terms can appear in both positions. Imho, only "idiomacy" can do that.)